# Omega - add new section

Tags: 7, theming

I would like to add a new section to my Omega sub-theme but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to do this.

By default there are only 3 sections: Header section, Content section & Footer section.

I would like to add another section to those 3 in order to assign different zones & regions to it.

Thanks

Comment: Docs are here: http://drupal.org/node/1222322. Sections are hard-coded so you'll have to patch Omega. The accepted alternative is to create a new _zone_ instead.

Comment: that's disappointing :(

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean, I was looking to do this a while back and came to the same conclusion. To be fair changing my methodology to use zones instead worked perfectly

Comment: @Clive: I can't accept it (I didn't ask it), but you should post that as an answer anyway.